# Notifications for new flights/routes from an airport?

Tags: air-travel, airports, routes, sin

COVID has decimated flight schedules, and while they're slowly trickling back, particularly here in Asia many previously common routes are still running on very limited schedules or halted entirely.

**Is there any service I can subscribe to be notified for additional flights?**  Particularly interested in `SIN`-`KIX` (Osaka-Kansai; used to be 5-6 flights/day, currently only served 1x by Singapore Airlines) and `SIN`-`LOP` (Lombok; used to be daily on SilkAir/Scoot, currently no flights).

Note that I am *not* interested in fare alerts, which is a reasonably common service, but not a solution to this question unless there's a way to limit the alert to nonstop flights.

Comment: Is it a duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/135684/1810?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Indeed, and looks like it even has an answer by me, saying no such thing exists.  Sigh, hope springs eternal...

Comment: I’ll add a +500 bounty on the original question :)